# LocalDateTime (Joda-Time) mapping in Hibernate 3.2.6.ga

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, jodatime

After many headaches with java.util.Date and Calendar I solved to use joda-time 1.3 in my project, but now I'm facing another problem. The project uses the Hibernate 3.2.6.ga version. In order to map the LocalDateTime class attribute I used org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime in hbm. When I tried to test the application I got the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes. So I noticed that joda-time hibernate I'm using (v 1.3) is for Hibernate > 3.6.0 version.

Changing the Hibernate version in my project would be painful. Is there another way to map LocalDateTime to a Date oracle column using joda time hibernate with 3.2.6.ga hibernate version?

Comment: Hibernate 3.2.6 is over four years old now. Do you not think it may be worth the pain of upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom UserType.
Create class that implements class *UserType* from Hibernate API.
All methods that you need to declarate, you can get from class *org/joda/time/contrib/hibernate/PersistentLocalDateTime*